# Passing a double pointer to a function to get starting address of linked list (C)

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, function-pointers

I am passing a double pointer to a function. The function reads data from a file into a linked list. I set CircuitData as the pointer to the first node. After I called the function and want to use CircuitData it is empty. Why does it not return the address of the first node(&newPtr)?

```
ListNodeType **CircuitData;
int numEl = 0;
int numNodes = 0;
CircuitData = NULL;

ReadFile(CircuitData, &numEl, &numNodes);
printf("%p", CircuitData);
```

Part of the ReadFile function that I'm calling:

```
void ReadFile(ListNodeType **CircuitData, int *numEl, int *numNodes){
    *numEl = 0;
    *numNodes = 0;

    ListNodeType *newPtr, *tempPtr;
    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNodeType));
    CircuitData = &newPtr;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
```

Comment: Your declared item should be `ListNodeType *CircuitData;`, the call should be `ReadFile(&CircuitData,...)`, and the assignment in the function should be `*CircuitData = newPtr;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the declared type of `CircuitData` should be a pointer:

```
ListNodeType* CircuitData;
```

To set the address stored in `CircuitData` (inside the ReadFile function) you would write

```
*CircuitData = newPtr;
```

This sets the data at the address `CircuitData` to the address stored in `newPtr`, which is what you want to do.

You also need to properly pass the address of the CircuitData pointer to the ReadFile function by calling

```
ReadFile(&CircuitData, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that values are passed by copy in C. Thus, this assignment inside `ReadFile`:

`CircuitData = &newPtr;`

Will not be propagated to the caller. I think that you wanted this instead:

```
*CircuitData = newPtr;
```

For this to work, `CircuitData` must point to a valid memory location, don't initialize it to `NULL`. You might want to do this instead:

```
ListNodeType *CircuitData;
```

And then call the function like this:

```
ReadFile(ListNodeType &CircuitData, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The calling code needs to be like this:

```
ListNodeType *CircuitData = NULL;

ReadFile(&CircuitData, &numEl, &numNodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define CircuitData as (ListNodeType *), and in function ReadFile, pass &CircuitData